# Magento 2 - Move Sign Out link at the last position in customer menu dropdown

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer, customer-account, topmenu

I want to move authorization-link at the last position in customer menu.
How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

Code from xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <referenceBlock  name="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link">
                 <arguments>
                     <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
                 </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
```

**UPDATE**

As per https://github.com/rostyslav-hymon/magento2/commit/727709bfba4951e4dca4be18cf10475e7e81970f
Changed code in Navigation.php

```
private function compare(SortLinkInterface $firstLink, SortLinkInterface $secondLink): int
    {
        //return  $secondLink->getSortOrder() <=> $firstLink->getSortOrder();
        return ($firstLink->getSortOrder() < $secondLink->getSortOrder()) ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Still no luck!